# Google analytics code not working on Opera

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have following code on my MyBB based website forum. Strangely it works fine on Chrome but I'm not receiving any events (in realtime view) when using Opera 45 (v45.0.2552.888).

Code is copied in footer template, in script tags as provided by Google, UA-XXXXXXXXX-X has replaced the actual Id.

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: Wow, what version of Opera are you using? for test purposes

Comment: Opera v45.0.2552.888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours looking into JS code and Google console, I found that new Opera browser has built-in Ad/Content blocker, which was also hindering Google Analytics to send events. So, only solution is disable content blocker.

So unless you whitelist your website, you don't get any events. This means you will not get any analytic events from users of new Opera by default.

Hope that helps.